# Python loop slowing down

Tags: python, loops, selenium, memory

I have a python loop, which uses selenium to get some data from a website and store that in a SQL Database. At the beginning every loop takes about one second but after some time it is slowing down more and more... I think the problem is  a memory problem but I don't know how to solve it.
This is my code:

```
count = 0
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
con = sql.connect(user="user", passwd="passwd", db="db", host="localhost")
cur = con.cursor()


def create():
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        driver.get('http://www.example.com/w')
    else:
        driver.get('http://www.example.com/p')
    name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='address']/h3").text
    name1 = name.split(" ")[0]
    name2 = name.split(" ")[1]
    test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='adr']").text
    test2 = test.replace("\n", " ")
    dd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//dl[@class='dl-horizontal')[1]/dd").text
    dd2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//dl[@class='dl-horizontal'])[2]/dd/a").text
    day = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//dl[@class='dl-horizontal'])[5]/dd").text
    i = "','"
    try:
        values = unidecode("'" + name1 + i + name2 + i + dd + i + dd2 + i + day + i + test2 + "'")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO accounts (name1,name2,dd,dd2,day,test2) VALUES (" + values + ")")
        con.commit()
        global anzahl
        anzahl += 1
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        gc.collect()

    except sql.Error as e:
        print("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        gc.collect()


start = time.time()

for _ in range(200):
    create()

cur.close()
con.close()
end = time.time()
```

I don't see anything what yould slow down the loop. I tried `gc.collect()` but it doesn't change anything.
What can i do to that my loop does not slow down after a some time?

Comment: I think maybe the site is restricting rapid automated access which it realises during the later iterations of the loops.

Comment: Why are you calling `gc.collect()`? This may slow down you code.

Comment: Also, that query is really bothering me. Change it to `cur.execute("""INSERT INTO accounts (name1, name2, dd, dd2, day, test2) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)""", (name1, name2, dd, dd2, day, test2))` and you can drop all the string formatting. Depending on which SQL you're using, you may need to change `?` to a different placeholder but currently you're open to SQL injection based on whatever you scrape from the website.

Comment: I'm sure it is a memory problem becouse everything else (like nano) is getting slow too
I use MySQLdb and it works great with the query

Comment: And stop commiting on every itteration, commit once, after all itterations are finished. Also, define global variable at top of your function

Answer (score 0):

Things that can slow down you code:

1. The web server, which can reduce bandwidth to prevent DoS,
2. You `driver` object?
3. Network (Database) can be slow,
4. I/O access (with `sys.stdout.write` and `print`), depending on the real stream. Is it a console?